# How to fix "package javafx.util does not exist" in maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx, javafx-8

My code build on jenkins working till few days back with jdk 1.8 and suddenly it started throwing exception javafx packages doesn't exist like

```
16:28:25 [ERROR] /home/jenkins/workspace/dev-compiler.build.pre-submit/dev-client/src/main/java/com/dev/monitor/javafx/config/ConfigController.java:[11,26] package javafx.collections does not exist
16:28:25 [ERROR] /home/jenkins/workspace/dev-compiler.build.pre-submit/dev-client/src/main/java/com/dev/monitor/javafx/AppView.java:[4,23] package javafx.geometry does not exist
16:28:25 [ERROR] /home/jenkins/workspace/dev-compiler.build.pre-submit/dev-client/src/main/java/com/dev/monitor/javafx/AppView.java:[9,36] package javafx.scene.control.TabPane does not exist
```

As I got to know from google javafx is not the part of jdk anymore. So I need to get javafx dependencies externally.

Do we have any maven plugin or configuration which can solve this problem.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is from JDK 11 Oracle has decoupled JavaFX from JDK. You can refer to below link
[JavaFX](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates) If you are using 1.8, JavaFX is bundled with JDK 8

[image]